# How to stop a running thread from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qthread

I want to put a Stop button to stop all threads except main thread. In order to do, this codes like belows have been written:

```
serialclass *obje = new serialclass();
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);
   QThread *thread = new QThread();
   obje->moveToThread(thread);
   connect(this,SIGNAL(signal_stop()),obje,SLOT(stop_thread()),Qt::UniqueConnection);                                                    
   thread->start();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_baslat_clicked() //başlat butonu
{
    connect(this,SIGNAL(signal()),obje,SLOT(function1()), Qt::UniqueConnection);
    emit signal();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_stop_clicked()
{
   qDebug()<<QThread::currentThreadId()<<"=current thread(main thread)";
   emit signal_stop();

}
```

In SerialClass part :

```
void serialclass::function1()

{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<99999;i++)
    {
        qDebug()<<i;
    }
}

void serialclass::stop_thread()
{
    qDebug()<<QThread::currentThreadId()<<"Serial thread";
    QThread::currentThread()->exit();
}
```

Now, When i push start button everthing works good.But, when i push start button and i push stop button while function1 is running, program crashs.

if i use sleep function instead of exit, Firstly function1 ends, after that sleep function starts.

What i have to do to stop child thread when they are working. I mean i dont want to wait their process. Want to Just stop

Comment: Do you have some `processEvents` calls or do you use local event loops  in `function1`?

Comment: I edited function1. Let say something like this. After 99999 shows, stop_threads is calling

Comment: Actually i dont know what is the eventprocess or event loop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment i put qApp->processEvents(); and it works :)

Comment: Don't do that. That is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're busy looping in a reimplemented thread, you should use `QThread::isInterruptionRequested()` to break out of the loop and immediately return from the `run()` function:

```
void serialclass::function1() {
  while (! thread()->isInterruptionRequested())
    msleep(10);
}
```

If you're using a `QThread` as-is for its event loop, you need to call its `quit()` method.

To factor it out:

```
void stop(QThread * thread) {
  thread->requestInterruption();
  thread->quit();
}
```

What you're doing in `function1()` is wrong. You should never block the thread that way. You're writing your code in pseudosynchronous style. Invert the control flow to always keep control in the event loop, and `QThread::quit()` will then work as expected.

Comment: This method works thank you for your reply, But i want to ask another question. How to continue to thread after requestinterruption() function? Start function doesn't work.

Comment: You need to ask a separate question. `start()` generally works :)

Comment: Yes start() function works. I made a mistake.  Thank you :)